# Error Expected Spy to have been called even though the method is spied in the test method

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing a jasmine test to test method call in angular. I amd testing a call the method  this.calculateRemainingDaysLeft in getOutstandingAgreements method.  I am currently getting error

```
Expected spy calculateRemainingDaysLeft to have been called.
```

I have tried the following in my test  but none of them are helping me to resolve the issue

```
  expect(component.calculateRemainingDaysLeft).toHaveBeenCalled();
 //expect(mockAgreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Component

```
 public getOutstandingAgreements(Id: number) {
    this.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(Id).subscribe((data: AgreementsModel[]) => {
         this.myData = data;
         if (this.myData) {
         this.agreementData = this.myData[0].data;
         this.agreementLength = this.myData.length;

         this.calculateRemainingDaysLeft(0);
        }
        });
    }
```

Test file

```
describe('AgreementComponent', () => {
  let component: AgreementComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AgreementComponent>;
  let  mockAgreementsService: AgreementsService;


  const mockAgreementsService: any = {
    getOutstandingAgreements(): Observable<AgreementsModel[]> {
        return Observable.of([]);
    },
    updateAgreement: () => Promise.resolve([])
};

  configureTestSuite(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SharedModule, FontAwesomeModule],
      declarations: [AgreementComponent, CustomScrollDirective],
      providers: [{ provide: UserService, useValue: mockUserService },
      { provide: AgreementsService, useValue: mockAgreementsService }]
    });
  });  




  fit('should not return data when  getOutstandingAgreements is called', () => {
    const response: AgreementsModel[] = [];
    let outStandingAgreementSpy: jasmine.Spy;
    let outStandingAgreementServiceSpy: jasmine.Spy;


    setupComponent();
    outStandingAgreementSpy = spyOn(component, 'getOutstandingAgreements').and.callThrough();
    outStandingAgreementServiceSpy = spyOn(mockAgreementsService, 'getOutstandingAgreements').and.returnValue( null);
    spyOn(component, 'calculateRemainingDaysLeft').and.callFake(function() {});
    //spyOn(component, 'calculateRemainingDaysLeft').and.callThrough();
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(outStandingAgreementSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.calculateRemainingDaysLeft).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines:

```
outStandingAgreementServiceSpy = spyOn(mockAgreementsService, 'getOutstandingAgreements').and.returnValue( null)
```

to:

```
outStandingAgreementServiceSpy = spyOn(mockAgreementsService, 'getOutstandingAgreements').and.returnValue( Observable.of(''))
```

Comment: Sorry just saw that you spy had a return value of null. Try changing it to Observable.of(<anything>) otherwise whatever is in your subscription cannot be called.